# Take screenshot with of PDF opened in a new tab

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, bots, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer to click on a link that opens a new tab, and take a screenshot of this tab using :

```
const pages = await browser.pages()
const new_page = pages[pages.length-1]
await new_page.screenshot()
```

but I made some research and I found that `browser.pages()` contains only the default blank pages and my current tab but not the new one.

Hence, when I take a screenshot, it takes a screenshot of the current tab.
To give you some context, the new tab is a PHP URL and it displays a pdf file. I tried `waitForNavigation`, `bringToFront` and nearly every possible `console.log()`.

Does anyone know how to help me?

Comment: Is the PDF file actually showing in the new tab or is a download triggered via `Content-Disposition` header?

Comment: It is showing in the new tab

Answer (score 0):

consider using targets:

1. [`browser.waitForTarget()`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.0.0&show=api-browserwaitfortargetpredicate-options)
2. [`browser.on('targetcreated')`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.0.0&show=api-event-targetcreated))
3. [`browser.targets()`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.0.0&show=api-browsertargets)

```
const page = await target.page()
await page.bringToFront()
await page.screenshot(...)
```

Comment: how can i make a screenshot with a target ?

Comment: `await (await target.page()).bringToFront()`

Comment: This doesn't work and I think it's because of the same issue. There are three targets but one is null. I think I have to download the pdf in my file system with the link of it in the page before rather than clicking on it, but I don't know how to do that either...